# Can Bazel show all analysis errors?

Tags: bazel

When I invoke a Bazel command and there are analysis errors, it only displays one of them. For example:

```
ERROR: /Users/oliver/src/github.com/monzo/wearedev/service.transaction-enrichment/handler/BUILD.bazel:3:1: target '//service.personal-account-signup/domain:go_default_library' is not visible from target '//service.transaction-enrichment/handler:go_default_library'. Check the visibility declaration of the former target if you think the dependency is legitimate
ERROR: /Users/oliver/src/github.com/monzo/wearedev/service.transaction-enrichment/handler/BUILD.bazel:3:1: target '//service.prepaid-bridge/domain:go_default_library' is not visible from target '//service.transaction-enrichment/handler:go_default_library'. Check the visibility declaration of the former target if you think the dependency is legitimate
ERROR: Analysis of target '//service.transaction-enrichment/handler:go_default_test' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//service.transaction-enrichment/handler:go_default_library' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.049s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

When I go and fix this specific visibility problem and re-run the command, I might see a new analysis error.

Does Bazel stop analysing when it encounters an error? Is there a way to get it to display *all* analysis errors to avoid needing to repeatedly run a command to flush out each error serially?

---

To be clear, the command I'm running is trying to build *multiple* targets, *several* of which fail to analyse. Even if it's only possible to output a single error per-target, is there a way to get it to at analyse all targets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't this what you are looking for? From CLI help (`bazel help --long build`).

```
  --[no]keep_going [-k] (a boolean; default: "false")
    Continue as much as possible after an error.  While the target that failed 
    and those that depend on it cannot be analyzed, other prerequisites of 
    these targets can be.
      Tags: eagerness_to_exit
```

Not sure this applies to all scenarios, but I've mangled a target and instead of error got:

```
WARNING: errors encountered while analyzing target '//xxx:xxx': it will not be built
```

And went on to the other targets specified.

Comment: I scanned the `--help` but totally missed that. Thank you.

Comment: There is a lot of output there / easy to miss stuff... I was just not sure if the answer could be that trivial. :) Have a good one.

Comment: Additionally, you can pass `--nobuild` to `bazel build --keep_going` to skip the execution phase and show only analysis phase errors.